# Is there a way in app script to access my co-workers calendars and check their availability?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to make a small script that, given a list of google account email addresses, tries to pair up people by trying to find slots where both are available and then would send an invite to both for that slot.

How can I access the primary calendars for these accounts (without subscribing first) or rather more generally, how can I check if a user is available?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) to make a [FreeBusy.query](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query) request. You can see some similar sample code in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@eric_koleda/script-it-one-click-calendar-booking-3993fa56f76e).